# Solve the differential equation $x^2y''+xy'-y=\frac{x^2}{2+x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the differential equation 
>   $$x^2y''+xy'-y=\frac{x^2}{2+x}$$

My attempt: put $x=e^z$ then $z=\log x$

and equation reduced to $\theta^2-1=\frac{e^{2z}}{2+e^z}$

so $y_c=c_1x+c_2\frac{1}{x}$

how to find particular integral

Comment: What is $\theta$?

Comment: An easier method to do it is via the substitution $y=vx$ and $z=\frac{dv}{dx}$, which reduces your ODE to a linear nonhomogeneous one:
$$\frac{dz}{dx}-\frac{z}{x^2}=\frac{x}{x+2}$$

Comment: Otherwise, if you want to proceed with your method, have you been taught [Variation of Parameters](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/VariationofParameters.aspx)?

Comment: @projectilemotion..yes

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above should give an explanation why. You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your complementary solution is correct. A more efficient method to do this is to recognize the left hand size as a homogeneous [Cauchy-Euler equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation) and use the ansatz $y=x^{\lambda}$. This will yield a quadratic:
$$x^2y''+xy'-y=0$$
$$\lambda (\lambda-1)+\lambda-1=0$$
$$\lambda^2-1=0$$
Therefore, $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_2=-1$, thus the fundamental set of solutions are $\{x,\frac{1}{x}\}$, which is as you have shown.

---

We can find a particular solution via [Variation of Parameters](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/VariationofParameters.aspx). Note that for a differential equation $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=f(x)$, we must solve the system:
$$\begin{cases} v_1'y_1+v_2'y_2=0 \\ v_1' y_1'+v_2' y_2'=f(x) \end{cases}$$
Where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are the two fundamental solutions to $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$. Hence, in your case, we have:
$$\begin{cases} v_1'\cdot x+v_2'\cdot \frac{1}{x}=0 \\ v_1'-v_2'\cdot \frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2+x} \end{cases}$$
Solving the above system by elimination, we see that the problem boils down to evaluating the following 2 integrals:
$$v_1=\int \frac{1}{2(x+2)}~dx\tag{1.1}$$
$$v_2=-\int \frac{x^2}{2(x+2)}~dx \tag{1.2}$$
Recall that Variation of Parameters assumes that the particular solution will be given in the form of $(2)$, therefore all you need to do is substitute the results from $(1.1)$ and $(1.2)$ you obtain.
$$y_p=v_1 y_1+v_2 y_2 \tag{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this
$$y''+\frac{y'}{x}-\frac{y}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2+x}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[y'+\frac{y}{x}\right]=\frac{1}{2+x}$$
$$y'+\frac{y}{x}=\ln|2+x|+C$$
$$y'x+y=x\ln|2+x|+Cx$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}[yx]=x\ln|2+x|+Cx$$
$$y=\frac{\int (x\ln|2+x|+Cx) dx}{x}$$